# How to set role name while registering a new user in magento?

Tags: magento

I have a problem in user role_name while registering a new user..

```
 $model->setRoleIds(array(101))
 ->setRoleUserId($model->getUserId())
 ->saveRelations();
```

I am using above lines while registering an new customer... The problem is I assiged role name(customers) for the role id(101).

But in database table (admin/role)..It showing the username as the role_name for the registered customers[database table]..

For registering customers I need to store customers as a role_name in admin/role table

How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Gave a try catch like this,

```
try {
        $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
        $role->setParent_id(5);
        $role->setTree_level(1);
        $role->setRole_type('U');
        $role->setUser_id($user_id);
        $role->save();
        echo "Your username: ".$username.", and password: ".$password;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

and it Worked. Here `parent Id` is my custom role id. `$user_id` is the id of user to whome role should be attached.